# Spring - How to upload image from folder to database

Tags: java, spring, image, upload

Hello im trying to do something like this:

```
 private Byte[] getImage() throws IOException {

        String imageUrl = ServletContext.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResource("static/anImage.jpg")
                .getFile();

        Byte[] byteObject = new Byte[imageUrl.getBytes().length];

        int i = 0;
        for (Byte b : imageUrl.getBytes()){
            byteObject[i++] = b;
        }
        return byteObject;
    }
```

But it's wrong. So how to pick up a file from specific directory? Thanks.

ps.
I can do something like this:

```
 File file = new File("image.jpg");
        byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

But still its a path only from the main folder. Dont know how to program for the resources/images folder.

Comment: You can read the file as a [Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) then get `inputstream` from resource and covert to bytes

Comment: ok. What excatly is the classpath:?  Its some kind of folder? resources?

Comment: Thanks, this is an excelent. I would accept it as an answer if you will post it.

Comment: Done! Deleted the comment and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring you can use [Resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) to achieve your goal:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("static/anImage.jpg"); 
byte[] bytes = resource.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use e.g. Apache Commons for convert a File to byte array. Read more [FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File input)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray(java.io.File))

The way you loading resources seems to be the proper one.

Ensure that the loaded file is in proper location (src/main/resources).

Do you have any particular error or stack trace which describes the issue.

Comment: Dzięki za pomoc, będę pisał po ang, żeby każdy rozumiał.  Thanks, didnt know something like FileUtils exists. It works good. But the problem is i dont know how to load file from the location like resources/static. The Servlet context doesnt work. So im looking for a way to pick files from directories.

Comment: What does "The Servlet context doesnt work" mean? Do you have any exceptions?

Comment: There are no exceptions. But the image isnt being uploaded and cant be displayed on the browser.  The reason is beacause the  imageUrl.getBytes().length  carries array of only 84 elements. But when i use   File file = new File("image.jpg"); and the image is in the projects main folder i can display it in the browser, it works and its array carries around 200.000 elements.  So i still cant load an image from a different path.

Comment: Now I see.

imageUrl is String so you have bytes from string with path.

Try to change imageUrl form string to file:


File fimageUrl = new File(
 getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("database.properties").getFile()
);


and it should start working.

Comment: I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'C:\Moje\IntelliJ%202020.1.2\WORK\projekt\shopBackend\target\classes\static\gow2.jpg' does not exist     Still i see the jpg in target/classes/ static.   Ill try the thing with classpath and resources that Edgar wrote